# Unable to locate button in Selenium using Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

I have this HTML code:

```
<button> class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
type="submit">Autentificare</button>
input type="hidden" name="next" value="/"/
```

Using below locator I'm not able to click on that button.

```
elem.find_element_by_link_text("Autentificare")
```

Can someone please help me out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<button></button>` HTML tag is not the same as a link `<a></a>`. So it cannot find it with the `find_element_by_link_text()` method, because it looks for link HTML tags.

If you want to find elements by text try the following:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Autentificare')]")
```

Comment: now im stuck at this: 
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Autentificare')]").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) . i cant manage to send the enter key in order to send the login info

Comment: this is the error  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Autentificare')]").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'

Comment: @AlexAlex You cannot send text to a button, you need to send text to an input. This sounds as another question, because your original question is about clicking. If the clicking works, accept the answer and ask a new question for the new issues :)